# Spring mvc with rest not able to convert object to json

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller

I am having a spring MVC application and I have added REST web service to it. So users can communicate with request and response using views and applications can consume the rest and use req and resp using json.

The web application part works fine, Problem is that the REST part is not working. Below is the initializer class

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext appContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        appContext.register(WebMvcConfig.class);
         
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "SpringDispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(appContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

         
    }
}
```

Web part is working fine but while calling rest I am getting error :

```
<h1>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</h1>
<hr class="line" />
<p><b>Type</b> Exception Report</p>
<p><b>Message</b> No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList</p>
<p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
</p>
<p><b>Exception</b></p>
<pre>org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.ArrayList
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:224)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:181)
org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:82)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:123)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:892)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I have added the jackson dependency in the maven pom

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

and my DTO class(returned from rest request) has all getters and setters using lombok

Please help in knowing what additional config needed to make the rest part work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem I forgot to add the annotation @EnableWebMvc over my configuration class. This allows a set of default converters.

After adding the annotation everything working